# Why does my Capybara feature test intermittently fail when waiting for Ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara

I'm using Capybara 2.13.0 and I've got a test that relies on an Ajax request adding dynamic content into the DOM.

```
test 'contact data becomes visible when providing the correct password' do
  login_as_researcher
  visit '/participants/3'
  assert page.has_css?("ul#redacted-contact-data")
  click_button('Unlock Contact Data')
  # Use the correct password
  fill_in('enter your password', with: 'password1')

  # Ajax happens here. It renders a partial and places it in the dom.
  click_button('Submit')
  # Test sometimes fails here..
  assert page.has_css?("ul#contact-data"), -> { page.body }

end
```

I've read a lot of articles that say Capybara automatically waits for elements to appear in the HTML and there's no need to manually tell Capybara to wait anymore, but I'm not experiencing this in my case.

75% of the time this test passes and when it does fail and the page is dumped, it contains the content of the partial rendered in the JS response instead of the full HTML page.

Any idea what's going on here? I can only assume it's due to how long it takes the server to respond the Ajax request each time and Capybara not waiting long enough in certain situations.

I've set `Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5` in my test_helper.

I've tried with both the selenium and poltergeist drivers and it makes no difference.

Here's the output from `test.log`

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-01 18:09:23 +0100
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Researcher Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "researchers".* FROM "researchers" WHERE "researchers"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://www.example.com/session/new
Filter chain halted as :researcher_only rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 30ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
Started GET "/session/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-01 18:09:23 +0100
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (9.5ms)
  Researcher Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "researchers".* FROM "researchers" WHERE "researchers"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 248ms (Views: 247.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
Started POST "/session" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-01 18:09:23 +0100
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "username"=>"nick1", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Enter"}
  Researcher Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "researchers".* FROM "researchers" WHERE "researchers"."username" = ? LIMIT 1  [["username", "nick1"]]
Redirected to http://www.example.com/
Completed 302 Found in 78ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-01 18:09:23 +0100
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Researcher Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "researchers".* FROM "researchers" WHERE "researchers"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 8.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
Started GET "/participants/3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-01 18:09:23 +0100
Processing by ParticipantsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
  Participant Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "participants".* FROM "participants" WHERE "participants"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  Researcher Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "researchers".* FROM "researchers" WHERE "researchers"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  ContactData Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "contact_data".* FROM "contact_data" WHERE "contact_data"."participant_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["participant_id", 3]]
  AlcoholService Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "alcohol_services".* FROM "alcohol_services" WHERE "alcohol_services"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 16]]
  Baseline Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "baselines".* FROM "baselines" WHERE "baselines"."participant_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["participant_id", 3]]
  Rendered participants/_unlock_contact_data.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered participants/_details.html.erb (52.8ms)
  Rendered participants/show.html.erb within layouts/application (58.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 94ms (Views: 69.9ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
Started POST "/participants/unlock_contact_data?participant_id=3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-01 18:09:24 +0100
Processing by ParticipantsController#unlock_contact_data as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "from"=>"show", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Submit", "participant_id"=>"3"}
  Researcher Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "researchers".* FROM "researchers" WHERE "researchers"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Participant Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "participants".* FROM "participants" WHERE "participants"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  ContactData Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "contact_data".* FROM "contact_data" WHERE "contact_data"."participant_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["participant_id", 3]]
  AlcoholService Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "alcohol_services".* FROM "alcohol_services" WHERE "alcohol_services"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 16]]
  Baseline Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "baselines".* FROM "baselines" WHERE "baselines"."participant_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["participant_id", 3]]
  Rendered participants/_details.html.erb (4.6ms)
  Rendered participants/unlock_contact_data.js.erb (6.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 81ms (Views: 10.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
```

Is there anything I might be missing?

Comment: Try setting `default_max_wait_time` to something like 30 - that will determine whether or not it is the page just taking a while to render.  Also, look in your test.log after a failure and see what request was actually made and what the browser responded with (check that it did actually respond with a :js response) . Also you shouldn't be asserting on `has_css?` because the error messages are useless. It looks like you're probably using minitest so rather, see https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#using-capybara-with-minitest and then use `assert_css`

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. I've increased `default_max_wait_time` to 30 and it's still happening. The server is definitely responding with the JS response each time.

One odd observation I've noticed is that if I comment out all of the other tests in this file and run this one only, it fails nearly every time. If there are more tests running then it has a higher chance of passing.

Do I possibly need to use Rspec and do something like `page.should have_css("ul#contact-data")`

Comment: Swapping from minitest to RSpec won't make a difference, the `assert_css`, `has_css?` and `have_css` methods all basically end up calling the same routines to check for the data.  Using one of the other is just personal preference.  What is your `login_as_researcher` defined as (Are you sure the user is actually getting logged in every time) ?  Run just the one test and add the relevant portion of your failing test.log to your question.

Comment: Also note, the way you've written your assertions isn't actually showing you the page content at the end of Capybaras waiting because you're getting the body before it even checks/rechecks for the content.   They should have been written  `assert page.has_css?("ul#contact-data"), -> { page.body }` so the `page.body` doesn't get evaluated until the assertion has failed

Comment: Thanks, I've added `test.log` output to the question.

Comment: The user is definitely logged in without issues. This is really strange as the test will pass sometimes.

Comment: The log looks fine at first glance,  Assuming it is rendering the `ul#contact-data` element in there then the only thing left would be that it is visible? it's not covered by a different element, or has a zero size on the page or something?  You could verify that by passing the 'visible:false' option to the assertion which would then ignore the requirement that the element be visible and just assert that it exists in the page somewhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143107/discussion-between-nick-shears-and-thomas-walpole).